# How do I get an exit code from an Amazon ECS Task?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

When I launch tasks in Amazon AWS ECS containers, I need to recover the exit code programmatically via the Java SDK.

It appears in the Amazon web interface, and in the SDK I can get a text-based failure reason, but is there a way to get the explicit exit code?

Answer (score 14):

This is how I'm getting the exit code of a task's specific container name

```bash
aws ecs describe-tasks \
  --cluster $ECS_CLUSTER \
  --tasks $TASK_ARN \
  --query "tasks[0].containers[?name=='$CONTAINER_NAME'].exitCode" \
  --output text
```

In a script

```bash
#!/bin/sh
AWS_PROFILE=default
ECS_CLUSTER=cluster_name
CONTAINER_NAME=migrate

# Run task and get its arn
# NOTE: many of the necessary cli inputs have been omitted here
TASK_ARN=$(aws ecs run-task \
  --cluster $ECS_CLUSTER \
  --query 'tasks[].taskArn' \
  --output text | rev | cut -d'/' -f1 | rev)

# Wait for ecs task to stop
aws ecs wait tasks-stopped \
  --cluster $ECS_CLUSTER \
  --tasks $TASK_ARN

# Get exit code
TASK_EXIT_CODE=$(aws ecs describe-tasks \
  --cluster $ECS_CLUSTER \
  --tasks $TASK_ARN \
  --query "tasks[0].containers[?name=='$CONTAINER_NAME'].exitCode" \
  --output text)

echo "The $TASK_ARN ran in ECS cluster $ECS_CLUSTER and its $CONTAINER_NAME returned exit code $TASK_EXIT_CODE"

# exit with the same code
exit $TASK_EXIT_CODE
```

If there are multiple containers, it would be good to `sum` the exit codes before exiting or check each individual container separately.

Answer (score 9):

The exit code is available through the [`DescribeTasks` API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeTasks.html) as `exitCode` for each of the containers.

Comment: Ah: since the task might have multiple containers, each container has its own exit code.

Comment: Yep, that's correct.  Each container may also have its own `reason`.